# Do you need a tablet to use a USB pen?

Tags: graphics-tablet

I see a lot of pens and tablets being sold separately and together. Do I need both or are there pens that will work on any surface?

Answer (score 1):

## No.

Pens are tied to tablets and can't be used without them.

The pens you see separately are most likely replacements for the original.

Comment: I think that a No answer to an either-or question that covers 100% of the possibilities is quite wrong...